# Email validation not working properly in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to validate email. Suppose if a customer give an email address like "demo@gmail" it gives an validation error. Email should be "demo@gmail.com".What is the code to do this validation.I do it but not working properly.My code in below:

```
$request->validate([
   'email'=>'required|email',
]);
```

Comment: I'd really recommend reading the docs at laravel's official website [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation)

Comment: Your code is correct. That's exactly what the documentation suggests. This is not the part that is not working properly.

Comment: if a client does not give .com (at the end of email id) he/she will face an validation error.I want this validation also but can't get it

Comment: emails don't have to end with `.com`

Answer (score 13):

The comments under the question are correct, BUT...

If you are looking for email validator with domain at the end, you can use this filter:

`'email' => 'email:filter'`

It uses the filter_var() method to check if the email is valid. Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-email for other email validation types.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to the email validation: `email:rfc,dns`.
According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-email), the default is *rfc*, which accepts emails without domain, so the *dns* rule is adding the domain check.

With the example it looks like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'email'=>'required|email:rfc,dns',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$rules = [
  'email' => 'required|email'
 ];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if (!$validator->fails()) {
}
```

Comment: if a client does not give .com (at the end of email id) he/she will face an validation error.I want this validation also but can't get it